# How to extract list of all columns name from BigQuery tables?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I have dataset containing multiple tables. I want to check the

1. unique columns list
2. col lists for all table.

I Tried:
this gave me df and then list of all table names

```
%%bigquery --project ProjectID df
SELECT* EXCEPT(is_typed) FROM tenjin.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
#sort list a-z of all the tables inside tenjin
all_tables = sorted(list(df.table_name))
```

now I want to run a loop or SQL query that can give me all columns name:

I tried

```
for table in all_tables:

print("bring magic unique columns list here")
print("columnslist")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, but depending on your needs I think you could skip a few steps by querying `<dataset-name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, e.g.

```
%%bigquery --project ProjectID df
SELECT * FROM tenjin.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

result = df.groupby("table_name").column_name.apply(list).to_dict()
```

The `to_dict` call is optional but may make life easier downstream. You can get your `all_tables` back as follows, for example:

```py
all_tables = sorted(list(result.keys()))
```